# Conda build unsatisfiable dependencies error with pint

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I have a valid pip package that I am trying to put onto the Anaconda.org server. I created the meta.yaml file with conda skeleton, which includes the requirement for pint (no particular version selected, so it should default to the latest.) However, when I attempt to build the package with conda build, conda raises this error:

`raise DependencyNeedsBuildingError(exc, subdir=subdir)
conda_build.exceptions.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform osx-64: ['pint']`

However, there is a pint that is built for osx-64... both in conda and in pip and on my machine - it's the one I use to run my pip package. What repository is conda hunting through to find that requirement and how can I specify the correct pint to use in meta.yaml?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conda is hunting through the channels in your configuration, which you can view with the command

```
conda config --get channels
```

(or `conda config --show`). Conda build always installs packages from the repositories (which is to say it doesn't rely on packages you have installed locally) because that is what a general user will do when they install your package. In your case, you need to add a channel to pick up the `pint` package; you can find a suitable channel by searching on Anaconda.org, and in this case, the `conda-forge` channel (among others, but that's the one I'd recommend) has the `pint` package. You can add the channel to your configuration with

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

or you can use it for this single build with the `-c` option to `conda build`:

```
conda build -c conda-forge your_package_name
```

See [`conda-build`](https://conda.io/docs/commands/build/conda-build.html) for more information.

Comment: If someone else has to build this, how do I communicate the channels they need to add within my package? I assume within the meta.yaml... Is there a standard way of specifying these build-requirement channels?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Since many channels can resolve a dependency (in general), the package maintainer shouldn't force people to use a particular channel. You can mention it in your docs though, so your users know what to do :-)